# Don't success to change the input width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making some project like that should look like http://jsbin.com

when I'm trying to change the input width it is does'nt success

```
var clickedHtml = "#EFEDEF";
var clickedCss = "#EFEDEF";
var clickedJs = "#EFEDEF";
var clickedRes = "#EFEDEF";

function inputSize() {
    var perc = 0;

    if (clickedHtml == "#818081") {
        perc++;
    }
    if (clickedCss == "#818081") {
        perc++;
    }
    if (clickedJs == "#818081") {
        perc++;
    }
    if (clickedRes == "#818081") {
        perc++;
    }

    if (perc != 0) {
        perc = 100 / perc;
    }

    return "\"" + perc.toString() + "%\"";
}

$("#htmlBut").click(function () {

    if (clickedHtml == "#EFEDEF") {
        $("#htmlBut").css("backgroundColor", "#818081");
        clickedHtml = "#818081";
    } else {
        $("#htmlBut").css("backgroundColor", "#EFEDEF");
        clickedHtml = "#EFEDEF";
    }

    $("#htmlField").css({
        width: inputSize(),
        display: 'block'
    });

});
```

- htmlField - input id.
- htmlBut - html button id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to just return the value as a string, no need to enclose it in ""

```
return perc.toString() + "%";
```

In your case the returned value `"50%"` is not valid, it should be just `50%`

Answer (score 2):

Return 'return  perc.toString() + "%";' from inputSize method.